# Why should I prefer checkState over assert?

Tags: java, guava

Is there any benefit of using checkState over assert? I remember reading somewhere that I should prefer checkState but I can't remember why.

Answer (score 2):

`checkState` and `assert` have totally different purposes.

`checkState` is a *precondition* check that throws an exception if a *caller* called your method when the program is in a state in which that method may not be called. (Meaning that they are using your code incorrectly; they should have been able to avoid calling that method at the wrong time by using it correctly.)

`assert` is generally at most a sanity check of something that you know *must* be true at that point in the program (kind of a compiled comment). Additionally, `assert` may be enabled or disabled depending on a flag when starting the JVM. It's typical to have it disabled in production. So it's not something you can rely on to break the flow of your method even if you do somehow get in a state that you're asserting is not possible.

Guava's new (as of 17.0) [`Verify`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Verify.html) class is something like an `assert` that is always enabled, but not exactly; it's for cases that should not occur, but could possibly if some outside service (i.e. one that your code is calling, not the code that's calling you) behaves in a way that it claims it shouldn't. See its Javadoc for more on the differences between `Preconditions`, `assert` and `Verify`.